# Sharepoint - Search effect on CAML query

Tags: search, crawling

If you switch off the Sharepoint Search application (or remove it for a particular host name). Would the standard CAML queries still work correctly please? and Would the index fields still be indexed. I mean that if you set an index on a particular field, this is in no way related to the Search Sefvice Application - correct?

I am using Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search has no connection to the CAML queries, so you can turn that off without any problems